# Changing text typed by keyboard on typing instantaneously

Tags: python, keyboard

I am a beginner and I am trying to write a program which changes the text as the keyboard types.

Example: If I type 'APPLE', I want to make it appear 'HWWSL' instead of "APPLE" (Yes. It is Caesar Cipher ROT-7). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this letter by letter. Try something like this:

```py
def cipher(letter):
    if letter == "A":
        return "B"

     # Other cipher syntax goes here

def cipher_loop():
    ciphered = False

    while not ciphered:
        letter = cipher(input("Letter to cipher:"))
        if not letter:
            ciphered = True
            print("Ciphered")
        else:
            print(letter)

    return


cipher_loop()
```

Comment: Can you please explain with two examples? I am still new at this, and it takes me some time to grasp it. Thanks again

Comment: Try my edit, it may help some. If there is something you don't understand, comment back on the specific thing. I'm online for a bit. Happy to help!

Comment: Thanks again. But this returns B after I press enter, i.e., after the input clause is executed. But I want it to change on keypress itself.

Comment: That is essentially the expected behavior as you would have to implement the logic for the Caesar Cipher to work correctly. What I'm envisioning you asking is "How do I see this in real time?". In a terminal environment you can't (at least not without some terminal hacking which I am not an expert in). To do what you want, you need to link everything up to a GUI environment like [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

Comment: Is there something you can do using keyboard module? I recently heard about it.

Comment: Let me check, give me a couple minutes.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the keyboard module as you'd be manipulating hardware until the program stops running, which could make you send wrong hotkeys if you're not careful. Sorry :/. Like i said, check the GUI library Tkinter.

Comment: No problem! Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Sure, thanks. But, can you please try it and tell me. Just for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: any letter or number or ... on the keyboard is one character and you should write them one by one in " " like  "A","P","P","L","E"

Comment: every letter and numbers on the keyboard is a character and they should be written separately